# How to change opacity of css property on scroll down?

Tags: jquery, css, scroll

I'm using shopify to create my webshop and I'm trying to change the opacity of my header when scrolling down, when i use the following code (hard-coded) my header gets the opacity of 0.5:

```
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
.header-section {
    position: sticky;
    z-index: 1000;
    top: 0;
    background: #fff;
    transition: all .3s;
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

But when I try the following code on javascriptm it does not work:

```
  //Change opacity
  var didScroll;
  var lastScrollTop = 0;
  var delta = 5;
  var navbarHeight = $('header').outerHeight();

  $(window).scroll(function(event){
      didScroll = true;
  });

  setInterval(function() {
      if (didScroll) {
          hasScrolled();
          didScroll = false;
      }
  }, 250);


  function hasScrolled() {

      var st = $(this).scrollTop();

      // Make sure they scroll more than delta
      if(Math.abs(lastScrollTop - st) <= delta)
          return;

      // If they scrolled down and are past the navbar, add class .nav-up.
      // This is necessary so you never see what is "behind" the navbar.
      if (st > lastScrollTop && st > navbarHeight){
          // Scroll Down
          $('.header-section').css("opacity", "0.5");
      } else {
          // Scroll Up
          if(st + $(window).height() < $(document).height()) {
          $('.header-section').css("opacity", "0.5");
          }
      }

      lastScrollTop = st;
  }
```

I cant find what I'm doing wrong, does anyone see my mistake?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It works, check this https://jsfiddle.net/hryfaxgd/

Comment: It doesnt work on my website? 

smartsnutrition.myshopify.com and password is "plazay"

Comment: Oh it does work, do you know how it can get back to opacity: 1.0 when its fully on top again?

Comment: Add this line to hasScrolled() 
if ($(window).scrollTop()==0) { $('.header-section').css("opacity", "1"); }

Comment: Where do I put this in hasScrolled()? On bottom or on top or in one of the if-else?

Comment: Anywhere in this function.